# How to use css selector get span data?

Tags: python, css, scrapy

This html file

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div class="float-r"> 
   <span id="artical_comment_cnt"><i></i>0</span> 
   <span><i class="view"></i><script src="/cms/plus/count.php?view=yes&amp;aid=20192&amp;mid=17" language="javascript"></script>778</span> 
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want get "0" and "778" , my Code is

```
comments = response.css(".float-r span#artical_comment_cnt::text").extract()[0]  
views = response.css("div.float-r span span::text").extract_first().extract()[0]
```

But result always NULL, how to fix it??

UPDATE

for id `artical_comment_cnt` is Global only
my answer is

```
In [2]: response.css("span#artical_comment_cnt::text").extract_first()
Out[2]: '0'
```

Comment: `var comments = document.querySelector('.float-r .artical_comment_cnt').innerText`

Answer (score 3):

You have some mistakes in the selectors.

To get the comment, you should write:

```
>>> response.css(".float-r span#artical_comment_cnt::text").extract_first()
'0'
```

`#artical_comment_cnt` instead of `.artical_comment_cnt`, `#` is for specify an id, `.` is for a class.

To get the view, you need to specify,
that you want the **second** span in div (.float-r) element,
`nth-child(2)` will do it.

```
>>> response.css("div.float-r span:nth-child(2)::text").extract_first()
'778'
```

`span:nth-child(2)` instead of `span span`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
comments = response.css(".float-r span#artical_comment_cnt::text").extract_first()
views = response.css("div.float-r span:nth-child(2)::text").extract_first()
```